# Does iron:router have an equivalent to Ember's transitionToRoute?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, meteor, routes

I need the ability to programmatically route to different pages. As far as I can tell the only way to actually render a route is from within the Route declaration as such:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  this.render('index');
});
```

What I'm looking for is the ability to from some arbitrary part of the code to transition to another route. i.e. `if(whatever) Route.transionToRoute('homepage');`

I by snooping around found that I could use Router.dispatch, but I got some buggy behavior that I believe originated from that usage, in addition I got some strange debug warnings in the console. It appears to be an internal method as I can't find any documentation on it.

Can what I've described be done with iron router?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router.route('/', function() {
   if(this.ready()){
     if(Meteor.user()){
       this.render('news');
     }else{
       Router.go('register');
     }
   }else{
     this.render('loading');
   }
});
```

It's pretty straightforward, first it waits for `this.ready()` if you have any subscriptions to be called, then if you are logged in (`Meteor.user()` object is available) it renderes news, otherwise it go to register path

Comment: Maybe spoke too soon :/ The redirect works, however the Meteor.user() doesn't work :( I'm having the same issue from another one of my questions, which is Meteor.user() or even Meteor.users.find().fetch().length always returns empty, however I can type that into my console and get a result??

Comment: Did you put into path this.subscribe('name').wait()?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the route controller, you can call:

```
this.redirect('routeNameOrURL');
```

If you are anywhere in you application, you do:

```
Router.go('routeNameOrURL');
```

Both will pop a new state to the browser history.

You can check Iron Router official Guide for details:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-redirects